# How to hide the folder name in the url internally using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How could we hide a directory on the url

Like,
    http://example.com/lens_galleries/peter-fonda/  to
    http://example.com/peter-fonda/
    internally ie keeping all the html load same.

Comment: I recommend doing some research before asking a question... http://wiki.dreamhost.com/More_.htaccess_mod_rewrite_examples

Answer (score 0):

If it's specifically for "peter-fonda" then you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^peter-fonda/(.*)$ /lens_galleries/peter-fonda/$1 [L]
```

But if it's for general folders in the "lens_galleries", then you can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/lens_galleries/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/lens_galleries/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lens_galleries/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess add :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^peter-fonda/(.*) lens_galleries/peter-fonda/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

if you get css issues use relative path